# Give Delete Access on Attached files on case To Other Specified users

Tags: contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

Whenever a Content Document is Uploaded on a record, I need to Share the file to a group of users and give delete Access to the same users.

I've Implemented a trigger to share the Document With the Users. The Users getting access to remove the File from the record.

here is my trigger on Content document link

```java
trigger ShareAndDeleteFiles on ContentDocumentLink (After insert, After Update) {
    
    If(trigger.IsInsert && trigger.IsAfter){
        System.debug('Calling Share files Method');
        FilesShareAndDeleteHandler.shareFiles(trigger.new);
    }
    
    If(trigger.IsUpdate && trigger.IsAfter){
        System.debug('Calling Delete files Method');
        FilesShareAndDeleteHandler.deleteFiles(trigger.oldmap, trigger.newMap);
    }

}
```

here is my trigger helper class

```java
     public class FilesShareAndDeleteHandler{
            public static void shareFiles(List<ContentDocumentLink> cdlList1){
               Set<Id> documentIdsForUsr = new Set<Id>();
                Set<Id> newDocumentIds = new Set<Id>();
                List<ContentDocumentLink> cdlList = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
                id userID = '0055g00000CKLykAAH';
                
                
                List<ContentDocumentLink> cdl=[SELECT id,LinkedEntityId,ContentDocument.title,ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId =:userID];  
                for(ContentDocumentLink cdLink:cdl){  
                    documentIdsForUsr.add(cdLink.ContentDocumentId);  
                } 
                for(ContentDocumentLink cdLink:cdlList1){  
                    
                    newDocumentIds.add(cdLink.ContentDocumentId);  
                }
                 
        
        
        for(ID id : newDocumentIds){
            
                    if(!documentIdsForUsr.contains(id)){     
                       
                        ContentDocumentLink cd = new ContentDocumentLink();
                        cd.ContentDocumentId = id;
                        cd.LinkedEntityId = userID;
                        cd.ShareType = 'C';
                        cd.Visibility = 'allusers';
                        cdlList.add(cd); 
                       system.debug('New Assignment Is being Created');
                        
                    }
                       }
               insert cdlList;
          
            }
            public static void deleteFiles(map<id,ContentDocumentLink> oldMapFiles,map<id,ContentDocumentLink> newMapFiles){
                set<id> linkedIds=new set<id>();
                list<ContentDocumentLink> filesToDelete =new list<ContentDocumentLink>();
                list<ContentDocumentLink> newCdl=new list<ContentDocumentLink>([select contentDocumentId,contentDocument.publishStatus from contentDocumentLink where contentDocumentId in: oldMapFiles.keyset()]);
                for(ContentDocumentLink cdl:oldMapFiles.values()){
                    if(oldMapFiles.get(cdl.id).contentDocument.publishStatus=='P'&& newMapFiles.get(cdl.id).contentDocument.publishStatus=='R'){
                        linkedIds.add(cdl.id);
                       
                    }
                }
                if(linkedIds!=null){
                filesToDelete =[ select contentDocumentId,contentDocument.publishStatus from contentDocumentLink where contentDocumentId in:linkedIds];
                
                delete filesToDelete;
                }
            }
        }
```

But after Removing, the file Remains in the Files Object.

Note: Removing Files from the record(Case) is **not even triggering as an Update event** on both Files object and case object. And it should be done **without giving modify all permission**.

Could You please help me giving Delete Access to the Other Users..

Comment: Is that goal that you want to give delete access to a set of users? Or that you just want to delete the original `ContentDocumentLink` record once you've assigned the new CDL to the user in question? You're saying the former, but your code seems to say the latter.

Comment: @pchittum yes i need to give delete  access to a set of users. so, first I've implemented a trigger to share the file with collaborator permission, and then implemented a trigger to delete the file from files after removing file from the record